# How can i redirect to the page using angular js while i am using javascript window.location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `javaScript` onsubmit function to redirect to particular page based on role. I am also using `AngularJS` in my app.but when i press enter after filling form the page is directly going to that page instead of loading the page in `ng-view`. how can i solve this?

code:

```
function next(){
    var role = location.search.substring(1);
    if ( role == "vp"){
        //alert ("Login successfully");
        window.location = "results.html?vp";//redirecting to other page
        //return false;
    }
    else{
        window.location = "results-locked.html?sales";
    }
}
```

Angular JS

```
var module = angular.module("portalApp", ['ngRoute']);

 module.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/home', {
                    templateUrl: 'home.html',
                }).

                when('/results', {
                    templateUrl: 'results.html',
                }).

                when('/lock-results', {
                    templateUrl: 'results-locked.html',
                }).

                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/home'
                });
        }]);
```

Html:

```
<div class="search-form">
  <form method="post" name="myform"  action="javascript:next()" class="ourform">
  <img src="images/mic.png" class="mic">
  <input type="search" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Type or speak here to search">
  <input type="image" alt="submit" src="images/search.jpg" class="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

instead i want some thing like `href="#/results"` and `href="#/results-locked"` in javascript.

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well? The code, where anchors are placed.

Comment: use $location.path();

Comment: You should use `ngSubmit` directive along with `$location.path();`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by modifying javascript code to

```
function next(){
    var role = location.search.substring(1);
    if ( role == "vp"){
        //alert ("Login successfully");
        window.location = "#/results";//redirecting to other page
        //return false;
    }
    else{
        window.location = "#/lock-results";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi angularjs works in two modes hashbang mode and html5 mode.

you can get the details from the link

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

so if in your anchor tag if you are using

```
<a href="home.html">go to home</a>
```

it will not work, so you have to 
activate the desired mode or you can directly use # in href attribute

```
<a href="#home.html">go to home</a>
```